# Trying to copy an Object to a Variable But Not Assigning All Properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

Here i have an err object coming from the error handler func
then i declared a new variable and tried to copy the the err object to new error var
it copies the first threee properties i.e the statusCode,operationalError and the success but it does not copies the message and stack property [image: Here is a Screeenshot of the code in debugger]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties `message` and `stack` are non-enumerable. And JS will not copy the non-enumerable properties.

To copy the non-enumerable properties you can use `defineProperties` and `getOwnPropertyDescriptors` as:-

```
error = Object.defineProperties({}, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(err))
```